# Testing IPN in Sandbox with MAMP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, sandbox

I’m getting INVALID IPN returns  using MAMP for development and testing with the PayPal Sandbox.

I have reviewed a few dozen of the more recent posts that relate to this issue and found no successful advice.

My MAMP setup passed the PayPal test for compliance with TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1
I have the May 2019 casert.pem bundle in the same directory as the listener.

All of the transaction variables in the Pay Now button are integers, money_format or urlencoded text. 
The transactions are COMPLETED. Sandbox IPN history has been unavailable since I started this test so HTTP code and other data are not available. (Can any one else access IPN history in the sandbox?)

The setup is essentially the same as a live application that has been working on a production site with SSL. So the obvious differences are: MAMP and no SSL (notify_url and return URLs are http and not https). However, I ran similar code in MAMP several months ago without problems.

I get a quick take on the error by holding the listener file open in my browser and refreshing it after I receive the correct ‘return’ PDT data. When live, the code sends emails on errors.

My code—leaving out the application code that runs if IPN verified--is pretty much a copy of the example code.

```
    <?php
    $paypal_url = “'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2)
             $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
         $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    } 
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
         if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
                    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
         } else {
                    $value = urlencode($value);
         }
         $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
        echo "curl_error($ch)";
        exit:
    }

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        echo "VERIFIED";
    } elseif (strcmp ($res, “INVALID”) == 0) {
        echo “INVALID”;
    }
    else {
        echo “NO IPN”;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: "If you are using PayPal’s instant Payment Notification (IPN) service, you will need to ensure that HTTPS is used when posting the message back to PayPal for verification. HTTP postbacks will no longer be supported."

Comment: Does this mean in the CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1)  or in the notify_url and return urls?  If the latter, it puts new requirements on test environments as distinct from production environments.  Note that the paypal_url is already https.

Comment: OK. I think I made a wrong assumption. Was thinking they were posting something back to you and required HTTPS for that. What exactly are you getting back? What is the error?

Comment: I'd be curious to see the body of the requests.

Comment: I don't see what the error is. I'm getting back "INVALID" as per the code above. I've never tried to print $req but will try to do that and submit.

Comment: I'm grateful for your curiousity. I added $req to the echo and go "INVALIDcmd=_notify-validate." So, I'm not sending the data back to PayPal. Can you see the error in the code. I'll be looking for it but welcome the assist.

Comment: Before the last test, I checked for IPN history in the sandbox and got in but found none. After the last test, I checked for IPN history and got the message I've been seeing for several days. "Sorry, this feature is currently unavailable. We apologize for any inconvenience." So, maybe this is a Sandbox problem and not a Frank problem.

Comment: After spending the last half hour trying to find a way to ask whether Sandbox IPN will be online soon, I ended up with a PayPal Tech Rep who told me to contact Sandbox but had no idea how I might go about doing that. Clearly, Sandbox IPN is sending something to me and I'm sending something back to them (apparently just "cvd='_notify-validate'" but no IPN history to indicate  what's going on. The PDT is complete and accurate.  I give up for now.

Comment: Look at URL encoding. `rawurldecode` vs `urldecode`. i.e. ASCII 32 vs 43. `+`. I know they, PayPal, use a weird date format. Seeing the payload I might see something. Just speculating now. Nor reassuring responses, tough when you don't know if it is on their end.

Comment: I tried rawurldecode and got the same INVALID response with truncated $req, which says to me that an IPN was sent but when I checked IPN history I get "No IPN messages were found for the past 24 hours." At least now I'm getting into the IPN history. I'll make another stab tomorrow and try again to contact Sandbox.